# How to invoke a function in javascript which has been declared in a html file

Tags: javascript

I have a html file with function `displayJsonWithAjax` and function `displayOtherJsonWithAjax` declared in a script-tag.

In another script-tag, I invoke those functions with this code when a select box change:

```
<script>
import fetchJson from 'some.module'

function displayJsonWithAjax() {
     ...
}

function displayOtherJsonWithAjax() {
     ...
}

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectBox').change(function () {
        displayJsonWithAjax();
        displayOtherJsonWithAjax();
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

When debugging with a browser, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: displayJsonWithAjax is not defined
```

If I try to put all the functions in the same script tag, no code is automatically executed when the browser load the page... How do I accomplish to call these two functions?

Comment: Can you show us the script tag as well?

Comment: show declaration of those functions

Comment: Can you re-produce this in a jsfiddle

Comment: It should have worked unless there is an error before: [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/73sv8seb/)

Comment: @Rajesh I am new to javascript. I don't know how to use the console. I am debugging in an editor and only get the error. How do I debug with chrome?

Comment: @Alex i am not sure how to accomplish this when I have module definitions and external libraries

Comment: @TEJacobsen Its alright. On chrome, press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I`. You can even refer following link for reference [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import fetchJson from 'some.module'`

Does that really work? Check you console.

If a script line fails, everything after that line won't be executed, so the script functions won't be declared and won't be usable elsewhere (and that will explain why "If I try to put all the functions in the same script tag, no code is automatically executed when the browser load the page": the script fails at line 1, and nothing else is executed).

Answer (score 0):

```js
test();
```

```html
<script>function test(){
alert('hello');
}</script>
```